# wkhtml library is not accepting second parameter in url?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtml library for html to pdf generation but it is not accepting second parameter in url?

```
exec('C://"Program Files"//wkhtmltopdf.exe ' . 'http://localhost/test.php?a=351&b=2' . ' ' . $file_name . '');
```

Is any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the command to a variable, echo it and try it out directly on the executable, not from PHP. That might give you a readable error.

Also, try to put the url in quotes, I just tried the following command and it worked nicely

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe "https://www.google.com/search?hl=fi&safe=off&biw=1195&bih=732&site=imghp&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=test&oq=test" test.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) (escapes & which causes the problem being a reserved character for shell commands )

```
$print_url = escapeshellarg("http"//site.com/print_page.php?arg1=$arg1&arg2=$arg2");
```

then:

```
$print = exec("/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf -T 0 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0  $print_url  $path/$file 2>&1");
```